# Wrong person identified by Google Photos

Tags: google-photos, facial-recognition

In my *People and Pets* album on Google Photos, it has done a very good job at identifying my friends and family, but there are a few errors (wrong person identified, two albums of the same person, friend not identified).

I cannot find a way to manually tell Google *this person is Joe Bloggs* etc. Is it possible? (Have tried on both the Android app and the webapp).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't tell Google who the person is, only who the person is *not*.

1. Open up the "People" album where there's a mistake
2. Select all of the photos that are mismarked as being for the current person
3. In the "More options" menu (three vertical dots) choose "Remove results"

If it all works well, you'll find those photos grouped together under a different "face" that you can rename and have Google identify them again.

---

For the instance of a person album without a name, just open up the album and add a name. It will draw names from your contacts, but you can include a manually created name as well.

---

For separate albums for the same person, make sure they're spelled *exactly* the same. In either case, it will work best if you have a Google Contacts entry for the person. Rename one to match the contact; you should be prompted "is this the same person?" and you can essentially "merge" the albums.

Comment: I remove results, but these photos reappear under the same wrong person again after 1 day. They don't appear as new person right away :(

Comment: Yep.  It's a Known limitation and the community discusses it often on their forums.  The full ability to manage custom tagging/faces was available in Picasa, but after they deprecated Picasa they left us with only a half-baked feature in Google Photos to date.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the "two different albums for the same person" problem by selecting their photos (individually) on the "people and pet" page, selecting "add a name" and tying them both to the same contact name (have to have them in your Google Contacts for this to work).

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for the necro, but another solution for merging 2 names/faces into 1 is just naming them the same name, Google Photos automatically asks if you'd like to merge the two names/faces.